# if I have a pair of Aces in my hand and the other players has a pair of kings with the board, who wins?

Tags: texas-hold-em

my hand: AA
other player's: K8
community cards: K79J3
who wins? is his pair stronger because of the community cards?

Answer (score 0):

You win. You have a pair of aces, he has a pair of kings.